# create web service client using java

Tags: web-services

I have the webservice connection url and it's methods.How to call the webservice in java.What are the requirement needed for that (import any api's).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you provide for information, and perhaps some code examples?

You don't state if its a java applet, application or servlet.

Generally speaking, in a java applet for example, to "POST" data you would need to create a direct socket connection, construct the correct header for an HTTP post, send it over the socket and then parse the incoming response, again directly.  Should be noted that an unsigned java applet can only make direct socket connections to the server it was downloaded from (CodeBase)

Hope this helps.

Darren 
[Spectral Software Design](http://www.spectralsoftware.net)